# Discord Bot Deployment Problems

Tags: github, heroku, discord, discord.js

I'm currently having problems with getting my Discord bot, RoboMiku, to go online.

There were 2 main problems I had, but they're fixed. But, I have a new problem.

### 1. Bot not going online

My problems with deploying her are gone, but now she doesn't go online. It might have to do with the fact that when I click on the domain created, it brings an error up. [Here is the link.](https://robomiku.herokuapp.com/)

If it helps, my code on GitHub is [here](https://robomiku.herokuapp.com/).

Comment: The Github repository is either private or does not exist, and have you included a Procfile with your dyno/worker definitions?

Comment: I did, but I made it private for some reason.

Comment: It is now public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key-value pairs should not have trailing commas in JSON files. So, removing the trailing comma from start script will solve your issue.

```
{
  "name": "robomiku",
  "description": "A simple bot that is currently in development.",
  "version": "0.0.6a",
  "main": "bot.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node bot.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^11.5.1"
  }
}
```

Fixing this problem should also fix your dyno issue.

Comment: Steam gamer, it worked, and it deployed, but if I click 'view', it now says there is an application error. Is there anything else that could fix this? (I also have been using VSC to host it locally, should I delete it?

Comment: Where is this view button, and what is the error in its entirety?

Comment: Once you deploy it, there is text that reads 'Your app was successfully deployed'. After that, there is a button that says 'View', which brings you to https://robomiku.herokuapp.com/. When you click it, it brings up an error message that says: ```Application error: 
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.``` I don't know what happened.